# Working with sessions when cookies are disabled?

Tags: php, html, session, cookies, sessionid

I have to make a timetable system and ive made a login in page which works, but then i need to use sessions to know whos login and if they are still logged in but the `cookies` have to be disabled so I have tried saving the `SessionID`'s to the `MySQL` database but i dont know how to then retrieve that session ID on another page, so any ideas will help? not sure if im on the right lines at all as well

Comment: Could you give a reason, why cookies have to be disabled? Other methods of passing the session-id are unsecure and vulnerable to session hijacking. Even strict browser settings normally allow short lived session-cookies (deleted after closing the browser), they are not the same as permanent cookies.

Comment: Just ive been asked to produce a system that can used when cookies are disabled

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to pass the session ID through the url, like so:

`http://local.domain/index.php?sessionID=7387837rhdfjfytyfegwfvkewbf`

Obviously the above `GET` request makes the session ID fairly obvious. Really though, in normal circumstances, only the users themselves will see it. So the security implications aren't terribly bad, but they are there for the malicious, to spoof a session.

**Tips for using this approach:**

- Don't use incremental sessionIDs (100, 101, 102) - [Generate random ID's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)
- Although you could use a `POST` request on every page, it doesn't help security and it'll probably upset/antagonise your user (Consider back button presses)
- Still maintain your session in the database, using the unique session ID from `$_GET` as the key
- Ensure that the session times out, and **quickly**. Update the `last_access` time with each refresh to ensure an active user doesn't time out.

Comment: That's a wrong way. Bcoz it is preferred to not show your session ID. It should be remianed hidden. It may be made in use for hacking. And if you want to use your session id, why not use session_start() at top of page.

Comment: @anujarora PHP stores its session ID in a cookie. If cookies are disabled, then you can't store the session ID. That leaves passing it through the url as the only viable option. I agree its not safe, but `session_start();` has nothing to do with this question. You need that regardless of whether cookies are enabled or not.

Comment: ok, i got that. and session_start(); is of no use. But I still say that this is not a good option. you can pass it as post values, or you can send a id at which the session is stored or you can encrypt the sessionID.

Comment: `POST` values aren't any more secure, they're just not as visible. Encrypting the `sessionID` wouldn't make it any more secure either. Encrypted, or not, it's still the key that can be used to unlock the front door, so to speak.

Comment: I have thought about doing it this way but like the comments have said its not very secure and i think it would be a better system if i used a database

Comment: @GeorgeHill - A database is server side, but you need to pass the session-id from the browser back to the server, so your software running on the server can recognize the user. A database can do nothing to solve this problem.

Comment: Can some one have a look at this link http://www.linuxforu.com/2009/01/server-side-sessions/

I think it might be my solution but dont fully understand the code :S

Comment: Having looked over that, albeit quickly, it appears that they're using the IP address of the client to recognise the session. This obviously isn't very secure either, as it could be a public computer or there could be multiple users behind a single router.

Comment: Yeah, just so confusing, just wish i could have cookies enabled

Comment: @GeorgeHill - I think your best bet is, to use the session-id in the url as Rawkode suggested, but make your site HTTPS only. Then you can hope that no url's are leaking out through link sharing. Even better of course, convince your client that he increases security with allowing session-cookies. Depending on your website, HTTP authentication may be an option too.

Comment: @Rawkode - Another important point is to regenerate the session-id on the login page, otherwise _session-fixation_ is all to easy.

Comment: http://4rapiddev.com/php/php-store-session-in-mysql-database/

Can anyone tell me if this code will help me with my problem ?

Comment: Still requires cookies, but I've already altered my answer with advice for using the url for your session.